# is libsqlite3.0.dylib missed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.3

I want to use sqlite in my iPhone app, but I read the first I have to do is add the framework, but it seems not to exists in my Mac.

As I read it is in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhone02.0.sdk/usr/lib/

but there is not, i looked for it with finder, but it havn't found the file (In Developer folder it's only an Application folder).

Should I install something?

I'm using Xcode4.3

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything to install, this is indeed already included in the iOS SDK.

Here is a short YouTube video to show you how adding a framework in Xcode 4 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-4TDlcsZRo

Hope this helps